# ConTeXt LMTX – incorrect spacing inside mathalignment

Tags: context

Please consider the following MWE –

```
\starttext
\startformula
\startmathalignment
\NC f(x) \NC = x_0 \NR
\NC y \NC = x_0^2 \NR
\stopmathalignment
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

which produces the following output

[image: incorrect-spacing]

As you can see, the spacing between the math expressions in the first column and the equals sign is incorrect: it seems to be the ord-ord spacing instead of the desired ord-bin spacing. Although, I don't have an older install of LMTX handy, I am certain that it was working fine just a few months back (I have made documents with it).

Am I doing something wrong? How do I enable this basic functionality?

I have seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655851/context-lmtx-mathalignment-does-not-work-properly) and the answer to it. However, the posted solution does not work.

Comment: Could you attach the full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/231/213149)? From the screenshot I can suggest a quick solution — to add `{}` before equal sign, so that  you have `\NC {}=`

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: @antshar this is the full MWE, it is for Context which has a much simpler syntax than LaTeX. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: For the OP: I can confirm that the spacing is correct when using an older TeX Live with mtx-context v. 2021.03.05, MKIV  fmt 2022.8.12 and LuaTeX  1.14.0.

Answer (score 1):

Your example compiles fine with the latest version.

[image: correctly aligned equations]

The math is currently actively developed, and during this time some temporary problems might appear.  The problem you show probably depends on some class information that was at some point not transported properly from one cell to the other in the alignments. (But I do not recall to have seen that in a release.)